# executing the same query for all the rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (myTable) with some columns which one of them is id (primary key).

```
id(primary key) col1 col2 ...
```

I want to calculate something with values of columns of each row, and put that in another table with id as a column and the calculated value as another column. I can now do this one by one by inserting to the new table(testResults), but I want to do it for all the rows.

```
insert into testResults (id , calculatedResult)
values(1, log(select col1 from myTable where id = 1));
```

Instead of mentioning id for each row, is it a way to fill the Result table with all the rows of the first table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
insert into testResults (id , calculatedResult)
    select id, log(col1)
    from myTable;
```